# Como chamar procedure utilizando Asp.net MVC com Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Em uma aplicação *asp.net mvc*, utilizando `ADO.NET` com *entity framework* e *mysql*, eu tenho uma `procedure`, que retorna uma listagem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CATEGORIAS()
BEGIN
    select * 
      from (select a.id,
                   @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum,
                   case when ifnull(a.categoria_id,0) = 0
                        then a.id
                        else a.categoria_id
                   end as grupo,
                   ifnull((select b.categoria_id
                             from categoria b, (select @rownum:=0) r
                            where b.id = a.categoria_id
                              and @rownum = 1), 0) || a.categoria_id || a.id as ordem,
                    a.nome
               from categoria a) as x
      order by grupo, rownum;
END
```

Como eu faço o call dessa procedure no meu código asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

primeiro você ter um modelo que represente os dados retornados pela procedure:

```
public class Categoria
{
    [Column(Name = "id", Order = 1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "rownum", Order = 2)]
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "grupo", Order = 3)]
    public int Grupo { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "ordem", Order = 4)]
    public int Ordem { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "nome", Order = 5)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Então você pode vir chamar a sua procedure da seguinte forma:

```
using(var context = new DataBaseContext())
{
    var resultado = context.Database.SqlQuery<Categoria>("SP_CATEGORIAS").ToList();
}
```

**Nota**

Ainda bem que esta stored procedure é do MySQL, se fosse no SQL Server iria sugerir a remoção do prefixo sp_ da mesma.

Comment: o context, posso utilizar a declaração var context = new minhaEntities() ?

Comment: sim, deve fazer assim.